# Finding an Irreducible Polynomial of Degree $2$ in $Z_p$

Tags: galois-theory

1. Consider $Z_p$ -- the field of congruence classes modulo $p$ (for $p$ prime).
2. I'm trying to show that $\exists f(x) \in Z_p[x]$ s.t. $f(x)$ is **irreducible and of degree $2$.**
3. I know that such an $f(x)$ must not have any roots, for if say $f([r]) = 0$ for $[r] \in Z_p$, then $(x - [r])$ would have to divide $f(x)$, contradicting its irreducibility.
4. Initially, I thought one answer could have been $x^2 - [p]^2$ since this polynomial doesn't have any roots in $Z_p$, but then I realized that $x^2 - [p]^2 = x^2 - [0]^2 = x^2 = (x+[0])(x+[0])$, meaning $x^2 - [p]^2$ isn't irreducible.

So how can I show that such an $f(x)$ exists in $Z_p[x]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way is: notice that $a^2=(-a)^2$, so that $a^2$ runs only over half of all the non-0 elements of $Z_p$ as $a$ runs over all the non-0 elements of $Z_p$. Choose $b$ which is not of the form $a^2$, then $x^2-b$ is irreducible. Works unless $p=2$ (when $1=-1$) - in that case use $x^2+x+1$.

Comment: Why does $a^2 = (-a)^2$ imply that $a^2$ ranges over only half of the non-zero elements of $Z_p$?  Trying some examples for $p = 3,5,7$, I can see this is true but what is the general reason?

Comment: I now see the reason.  $1^2 = (p-1)^2$, $2^2 = (p-2)^2$,... so that only half of the non-zero congruence classes are in this range.

Answer (score 2):

One method is a straightforward counting argument:

- How many polynomials are there of the form $x^2 + ax + b$?
- How many polynomials are there of the form $(x-a)(x-b)$?

Another method is to observe that $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the set of roots to $x^p - x$, but $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ is the set of roots of $x^{p^2} - x$.